# Advice on my second batch

Tags: hops, dry-hop, ipa, late-addition

I recently completed my first batch, which was the DIPA kit from Brewer's Best.  It actually turned out much better than I could have imagined, so I was very pleased.  My only complaints, and these were confirmed by friends who tried it, was that while it had a bitter taste, it didn't have a distinctively hoppy taste.  It also had a pleasant aroma, but the aroma was not long lasting.

The hop profile of the kit was Columbus hops added at 0 min and 45 min of the 60 min boil, and then cascade hops added at the end for aroma.

I want to get a bit creative for my second batch, and try to use this kit again but add in some additional hops.

Based on all of the material I have read, the general rule of thumb is early hops for bittering, middle hops for flavoring, and late hops for aroma.

What I want to try is the following hop profile (I did some analysis on characteristics of hops, and picked some I think could be interesting);

Bittering Hops - Simcoe and Chinook

Flavoring Hops - Warrior and Columbus

Aroma - Cascade

I then want to dry hop with Glacier and Palisade.

My question is, with this many hop additions, do I boil for more than 60 minutes?  Is there a right or wrong way to make multiple hop additions during a boil?  A set amount of time I should wait between each addition?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a double IPA, I suggest a moderate-to-high bitterness and a massive hop flavor, with ABV in the 7.5-10% range.

Denny is right-- You can really play with those hop additions and find your own groove. Remember, the later the addition, the more flavor in the final product.

Given your specific hop requirements, here's what I would do for a 60 minute boil. Times are *relative to the completion* of the boil:

**Bittering Hops - Simcoe and Chinook**

- 1/2 oz each of Chinook and Simcoe pellets.
- Add at 60 min.

**Flavoring Hops - Warrior and Columbus**

- 1 oz each of Warrior and Columbus pellets.
- Add at 10 min.

**Aroma - Cascade**

- 2 oz of Cascade pellets.
- Add at flameout; whirlpool for 5 min.

**Dry hop - Glacier and Palisade**

- 2 oz each of Glacier and Palisade.
- Add to the primary after 7 days.
- Leave in for 7 days.

**Here is a (sample) double IPA recipe that follows this hop schedule:** https://www.brewtoad.com/recipes/sample-iipa

However, some additional advice, if I may:

Consider that you may be "just going with the crowd" in terms of recipe generation. What I mean is... the strict concepts of "flavoring" and "aroma" hop additions are misleading; you actually get flavor and aroma from any late hop additions, with aroma especially increasing for later, cooler-temperature hop additions.

Hopefully that made sense. Happy brewing!

Answer (score 1):

Boil time is not dependent on hop additions.  There is no set time to wait.  You can add whatever you like whenever you like to get the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to simplify your batch and increase the hop flavor and aroma, I'd make the following recommendations:  Use just Simcoe for your bittering.  It's likely you won't notice much of a difference in using or two types of hops since all of the aroma and hop flavor will boil off, leaving you with just bitterness.  For your flavor hops, move them forward to the last 10 minutes of the boil.  If you want a lot of extra hop aroma to compliment the flavor, I'd recommend a hop stand for your Cascade. That simply means that once you hit 0 minutes left, you turn off the heat, toss in your aroma hops, and let it sit for 30-60 minutes (I've only ever gone for 30 with great results).  Letting your hops sit in the kettle at near boiling temperatures, above 175°F will give you a little bit of bitterness, but mostly aroma.

You'll also want to be mindful of what types and how much you are adding.  If you are substituting from the kit, that's one thing, but if you're adding to the kit, you may find the hops to be quite harsh in high amounts.  You're using two well known bittering hops for flavor, which while certainly doable, may give you a significantly pungent flavor.  If I were formulating the recipe for my palette (which may not necessarily be the same as yours, I just love hoppy, dry IPAs), I'd move the chinook from bittering down to flavor, remove one of the two, probably columbus, and use that alongside your cascade for aroma.  Finally I'd try and pair the cascade aroma with something similar in flavor by adding Centennial alongside Warrior and Chinook for your flavor addition.  Quantities would depend on the OG of the ale.  All in all I'd have Simcoe for bittering, Chinook, Warrior, and Centennial for flavor, and cascade and columbus for aroma.  An alternative would be to switch the Simcoe and Columbus around if you wanted a nice piny aroma with a clean bitterness.

Also, just to be clear, a lot of times people will refer to boil times in descending order.  Therefor, your bitterness would be 60, flavor 10, aroma 0.  Just wanted to be clear so you didn't read my suggestion as adding your flavor at 50 minutes when I meant 10 minutes left in the boil.